# Traveling for the very first time to Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

This is my very first time travelling. I am relocating alone to Munich, Germany in a few days. I have obtained a one-year Blue Card visa and I am going to work there as an IT Engineer.

I have the following questions and would appreciate your input:

- What questions should I expect upon my arrival at the airport while going through the immigration security check?
- What documents should I prepare before getting off the plane for the immigration officer? Should I prepare my employment contract, rental contract, airplane ticket, onboarding pass...?
- How long does it usually take to get off the plane, finish the immigration check process and pick up my bags (I need this one because I will be going straight to my apartment and I need to let the agent know if I am a bit late)?

Comment: Without knowning your citizenship, this question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, the word visa is spelled in lower case if not a payment card or the start of a sentence.

Comment: You are probably overthinking it. A *tourist* needs to explain that he or she is going to leave again, and possibly show the *return* ticket. An *immigrant* needs to show who he or she is. It won't matter much which plane you came on, because you are going to stay. So the questions will be those to check if it is your Blue Card. Your answers need to be in character for a professional who just went through a lengthy air trip. Keep all your documents in your carry-on luggage.

Comment: you should already have either your blue card or some temporary substitute for this (temporary papers, or D visa in your passport) which confirm that you have permission to work. At the airport they will ask why you are here, you are here to work, you already have permission to work as evidenced by this document. You do not need to show all your papers again - they don't have time for this at the airport - unless they suspect you are lying.